# Refresh the page after click OK on alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

In checkout page of my magento store, I need to clear some inputs when an alert box is showed and user press OK. Is possible to do that?

I have no control over the javascript alert. So I think in a script that detect an alert with a specific message and clear inputs when button of that alert is clicked.

**UPDATE**

Fixed!

file: opcheckout.js
line: 888

I add `location.reload();` because `document.location.reload(true);` not work on IE. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Could you clarify on which action magento shows alert?

Comment: @ArtemLatyshev I am using a payment module with credit cards and need to modify it to be accepted by the credit card company. When the customer inserts a number of invalid credit card and click on Place order button, the module displays a message (alert).

Answer (score 3):

Probably try overriding default alert and write a custom function like below,

```
var c_alert = alert;

window.alert = function (str) { //override default alert
    c_alert(str + ' my message');
    location.reload();
    //or write code to clear input fields here
}

//below seems to be triggered from somewhere where you don't have control.
alert('test');
```

Comment: I believe Magento is generating the alert from this line: Mage::throwException($this->_getHelper()->__('Payment Denied.'));

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
if(confirm('your confirmation text')){
document.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: I tried this way. But this is a confirmation box. And I need to refresh the page after clicking OK in the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

Make it refresh after the alert. The javascript code shouldn't execute before the alert is gone

Comment: Is exactly what I'm trying to do. But how in magento?